# Before update trigger sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I know before update doesn't exist in sql server. However I need to perform something particular and I have no clue how to do it.

I have 2 tables.

```
> Number 1 is the parent
> Number 2 are childs
```

> When my parent is updated, I need to use data from child to insert
>   inside another table using a trigger.

Thing is, in the program (proprietary so I can't modify it) the Parent is updated BEFORE childs.

> So my new table is always 1 update late.

Putting a trigger inside child will cause A LOT of insert/delete so it's not an option.

Do you guys see a solution from your POV ?

If that's not clear enough, I will update my post.

Thanks

Comment: Why not put the trigger on the parent table?

Comment: In MSSQL Before trigger doesn't exists, only after, you can 'circumvent' using an instead of (but table will be the same as after trigger). Also MSSQL doesn't support row-trigger.

Comment: By the looks of it, If I where you, I'll be updating the parent table, put trigger on the parent table, then when the trigger is used, put the data that you need from the child table into another table using the trigger created on the parent table.

Comment: The parent is updated before the childs. But you need data from the childs for your trigger. So the only way is to trigger on the child update, but how will you know when the last child for this parent is updated ?

Comment: Maybe you can use 2 triggers. One on the child table that will update some column in the parent table. than on the trigger on the parent table you can check if that column is updated, and if so, you know on your parent trigger that the child is also updated and you have all the data you need

Comment: I am using a trigger on the Parent atm. I have to insert 8 row inside another table. But as I said, always 1 update late. It means, the data are correct, but always 1 update late. Is it possible to update the parent inside the trigger wich is after parent update without being recursive ? Like being recursive but only 1 time ?

Comment: you will have to explain that better, I have no clue what you are trying to achieve. Add some sample data to your question and expected outcome that will help us understand what you mean

Comment: Try to make your question *a little less abstract*. I.e. give us *actual* toy table definitions for all 3 tables (just the relevant columns), then an actual set of insert/update/delete statements that "the application" would run (if it were working against the toy rather than the real tables) and then explain *what state* you need the data to be and when.